# Easiest way to add raw Open XML code to a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to insert a chunk of formatted text into a Word document in VBA. Since this will be done server-side, I am not advised take these chunks from another Word document using Office Interop ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757#/en-us/kb/257757)), so I presume it would be easiest to use Open XML like this `<w:p><w:r><w:t>String from WriteToWordDoc method.</w:t></w:r></w:p>` Sadly `Application.ActiveDocument.Range.InsertXML` fails. So what other quick and dirty alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "bare necessities" see this MSDN article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423225.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It describes what the minimum requirements are for inserting Open XML into an open Word document. Don't worry that the discussion targets Web add-ins - the principle is the same for any API that inserts WordOpenXML into a Word document at run-time.

I may be misunderstanding where "server-side" is involved in your process, so forgive me if the following is not relevant to your situation: Note that using VBA server-side is a bad idea - Word is not designed to run in a server environment. Better would be to use the Open XML SDK both to retrieve and write the information between two Word documents.

Comment: "Bare necessities" is creating a full document :/

Comment: Full document, server-side: The Open XML (SDK) route is definitely the way to go! If you need to insert complete documents with formatting, look for information on using the "altChunk" technique which supports RTF, HTML and Word file formats. This is simplest to implement. If these are Word documents it's also fairly simple to "stream" the content into the target document.